# Finding sum of all pixel values in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I want to find the sum of all pixel values of a gray image(Mat type). For that i need to access each pixel's intensity value. How can I do this in java?
I'm using opencv library with it. 
In OpenCV we can use the following code:

```
 for(int j=r.y;j<(r.y+r.height);j++)
    {
      for (int i=r.x;i<(r.x+r.width);i++)
      {
         int d= gray_image.at<uchar>(j,i);
         sum+=d;
      }
    }
```

Please suggest a solution to code it in java.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use `Mat::get()` and `Mat::put()`

```
double[] Mat::get(int row, int col)
```

Example :

```
double[] data = A.get(i, j);
```

Comment: Here, gray_image is of Mat type and when I'm summing (sum+=d) then I'm getting the following error:        ""The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) double[], double[]""

Comment: You should not add "double[]" to "double[]" directly!